# Shopping platform with user accounts tied to a credit card, "stored" payment cards

Tags: ecommerce, mobile, saas

I'm starting work on an app where I'm going to sell consumable physical products, and subscriptions for said products.

I want to have a user account tied to a credit card, to lower the barrier for additional purchases.

I've looked around the web, and found Shopify to be very close to what I needed. The problem with Shopify, is that they do not provide support for additional payment gateways in their mobile API's (except Apple pay, which is unavailable in my country).

The Shopify default payment gateway requires you to enter credit card details every time, as they have no long lived payment tokens.

I also need a user profile so people can manage their subscriptions with ease.

Now, I could set off building a custom solution on top of systems like Google App Engine, but I would rather spend my efforts on the customer facing app.

Does anyone know of any systems that satisfy the following requirements:

- User authentication and profile
- "Stored" payment cards (tokens for PCI compliance)
- Cart checkout
- Recurring payment
- Product inventory
- Backoffice for tracking sales, and handling service